# Maximum number of nodes with height h

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

How is $\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}$ the maximum possible number of nodes at height $h$ for a binary search tree or heap tree? I saw this as proof to asymptotically bound the `build_heap` function in the book, but I don't get it.

Comment: What book? What have you tried? Also, the answer is likely "It just is, here's a proof." Try proving and/or finding a counter-example!

Comment: Is it assumed that the tree is balanced?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the tree is balanced or not; this is just the maximum possible number of nodes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually touched upon this in response to your previous [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-calling-successor-n-times-during-tree-traversal), but the general idea is that there are $n$ nodes in a binary tree, and starting from the root, at each depth there is: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ... maximum nodes. We see that at the greatest depth, there is (at most) half of all nodes ($n/2$). Remember that the height of a node is the distance from the node to a leaf, such that the height of a leaf is 0 (and the height of the root is the height of the tree). So for a leaf, $\frac{n}{2^{0+1}}=n/2$. For the root, $h=\log_2 n$, so $\frac{n}{2^{\log_2 n+1}}=n/n=1$. And the rest of the tree follows from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a [full binary tree](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Graphics/FullBinary.jpg&imgrefurl=http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html&h=300&w=320&sz=15&tbnid=0hgAEf7vp52KeM%3a&tbnh=100&tbnw=107&zoom=1&usg=__Ms29uQFAAlrubNnqOJFBGVO2-dw=&docid=I5pV9WjyQhVdiM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gHqTULHOHMyrrAe9jYC4Ag&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQ9QEwAw&dur=3515) to support maximum number of nodes at a particular height.

A full binary tree (sometimes proper binary tree or 2-tree or strictly binary tree) is a tree in which every node other than the leaves has two children.

At successive level, number of nodes would be $1, 2, 4, 8,\ldots,n/2$.

For $h=0$, nodes = $\frac{n}{2^{0+1}} = \frac n2$.

For $h=\log_2n$, nodes = $\frac{n}{2^{\log_2n+1}} = 1$.

Comment: Usually a [2-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-tree) means something else.